# Twig "trim" not working as expected

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Using this Twig template:

```
{% for line in lines%}
    {{line}} after trim('.php') is: {{line|trim('.php')}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Using a controller in Silex to render the above template:

```
$app->get('/try', function () use ($app)
{
    $lines=[];
    $lines[]='123.php';
    $lines[]='news.php';
    $lines[]='map.php';

    return $app['twig']->render('try.html.twig', ['lines'=>$lines]);
}
    );
```

I receive the following output:

```
123.php after trim('.php') is: 123
news.php after trim('.php') is: news
map.php after trim('.php') is: ma
```

Note the last trim: `map.php` should become `map` but is now `ma`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is expected behavior.

`trim()` does not trim a substring but list of characters instead.

So:

```
map.php after trim('.php') is: ma

map.php -> does it start/end with any of ['.php'] -> TRUE  -> map.ph
map.ph  -> does it start/end with any of ['.php'] -> TRUE  -> map.p
map.p   -> does it start/end with any of ['.php'] -> TRUE  -> map.
map.    -> does it start/end with any of ['.php'] -> TRUE  -> map
map     -> does it start/end with any of ['.php'] -> TRUE  -> ma
ma      -> does it start/end with any of ['.php'] -> FALSE -> ma
```

It acts exactly like: [**php's trim()**](http://php.net/trim)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well explained. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As per the other listed answers, you're misinterpreting how Twig's `trim` function works (which uses the argument as a character map).

What you are probably looking for is the [`replace`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html) filter instead:

```
{% for line in lines %}
    {{ line }} after replace({'.php': ''}) is: {{ line|replace({'.php': ''}) }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This solves my issue. I am using replace now. But the correct grammar is like this: `line|replace({'.php' : ''})`

Answer (score 2):

Trim (as with the actual PHP function) uses the argument (or 2nd argument in regular PHP) as a character map rather than a set string.

This argument could be better explained as `a list of characters that, if found in any order, will be trimmed from the beginning or end of the given string`.